# Reactnavigation with parameters

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using [React navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) I am looking for a way to pass parameters into my navigation stack as follows. I have actually one screen which I want to use X amount of times. It only needs an url and a title,  and based on the url it should do exactly the same for each url.

So i want to create an object like so:

```
const urls = {
  {title: 'foo', url: 'https://someurl'},
  {title: 'bar', url: 'https://someotherurl'}
}
```

And now in my Navigation component I would like to do something like:

```
export default createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
 SomeKey: {
   // Loop here over the urls and create a component and pass props.
 }   
});
```

My issue is that I can't find in the documentation how to pass the `title` and `url` parameter via the navigator to the specific screens.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with one part, you can pass variables from Navigator like this

```
export default createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
 ScreenOne: {
   screen:props=> <ScreenOne {...props} screenProps={yourpropsr}/>
 }   
});
```

The documentation has example for StackNavigator but I hope this will work for TabNavigator too. [Documentation link here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigator-props)

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar in my app, but I'm grabbing my array from an API and build my navigation upon that. For each item in my array, I build the same screen setup in a tab navigation and have them all available from a drawer navigator.

You could do something like this:

```
let NavigatorConfig = {};

urls.forEach(item => {
    NavigatorConfig = {
        ...NavigatorConfig,
        [item.title]: {
            screen: props => <MyComponent {...props} url={item.url} />
        }
    };
});

export default createMaterialTopTabNavigator(NavigatorConfig);
```